# How can I edit a view in MySQL Workbench without it auto prefixing a database name to the tables/views used

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

When I create a view, I create it in the context of the default database.  So none of my references to table have a prefix which explicitly specify a database.  However, when I edit a view in Workbench it automatically adds the database prefix!

I don't want the database prefix because when I restore a database under a different name it causes the restore to fail.

Is this possible to stop the prefixing in a view edit or there another way to get round the restore issue?

Answer (score 1):

see https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85176

The mysql 8.0.3 or above has been fixed

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. Views are stored in specific databases, not in some space "above" all databases. Consider following...

```
use playground_a; /*or whatever database*/
create view view_whatever as 
select * from table_whatever;

use playground_b;
select * from view_whatever; /*here you will get an error that view_whatever does not exist*/
select * from playground_a.view_whatever; /*this works*/
```

That's why there will always be database prefixes in the view definition.

The only possibility I see, would be to use a stored procedure with a database name as parameter. In the procedure you'd use a prepared statement to execute a concated string of your query and the database name parameter. Of course this comes with downsides, like i.e. you can't add a where clause easily.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the view without explicitely specifying a schema is a convenience feature. Behind the scenes the view is still saved in a specific schema (the default one in this case). When editing the source code is retrieved from the server which returns the real code (including the schema qualification). Hence already when you send the view code the association happens and cannot be removed again later.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the command I use to create the backup:

```
mysqldump -u xxxxxx -pxxxxxx --routines database_a | gzip -9 > $FULLGZIPPATH
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't easily able to update to MySQL 8.X then a workaround I've implemented was a post-processing step performed on the dump file itself prior to importing. I just remove the explicit prefixed db name, since the import process / view creation doesn't need it.

```
PowerShell -Command ^
 "filter replace-dbname { $_ -replace '`<DB_NAME>`.`', '`' }"^
 "Get-Content dump.sql -ReadCount 10 | replace-dbname | Add-Content replaced_dump.sql"
```

I've used PowerShell since I'm on Windows, but any scripting language will do. The only notes are that:

- You'll need to do the replacement a-few-lines-at-a-time if you can't afford to read the entire dump into memory. Our dumps are about 11GB, which'd be a strain on our testing server's resources.
- In my script I'm not doing an in-place string replacement, so it'll create a new dump file `replaced_dump.sql` alongside the original `dump.sql`. For me this was useful for diagnostics, because it meant if there was an issue, I didn't have to dump it again. Again, depending on your dump/disk size this might be an issue.
- If your database happens to have `` `<DB_NAME>`.` `` as content in something like a text-field, this basic approach will also remove the string there as well.